# Regex for some numbers but not all

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I need to make a regex for only

```
A03
A07
A08
A14
A18
A21
A22
A25
A26
A28
A29
A40
A63
A65
A66
A68
A89
```

But it can not include `A07 A09`

```
A15
A16
A17
A19
A23
A24
A35
A36
A43
A46
A47
A52
A53
A55
A57
A62
A67
A67
```

I came up with this regex `^A[0-9]{1,2}(?!(?:09|16|15|17|19|23|24|35|36|43|46|47|52|53|55|57|62|67|70|72|73|75|77|79|83|84|87)$)` but it does not seem to work currently.

Would anyone know the best way to go about this?

Comment: What _range_ of absolute numbers is it ? Also, is preceding 0's ok or not, or is there a minimum number of columns of digits? Please be specific or it's a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `/^A(03|07|09|...)$/` for whatever numerical values you do want. Using negative lookahead exclusions is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this:

```
^A(0[378]|1[48]|2[125689]|40|6[35689]|89)$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/GNwLJW/2)**

[image]

The idea is just to use the positive matches you want. You could write all the alternations but that will create a very bad performance regex. Using character classes and alternations will do the trick

Comment: Just curious, can you run this regex http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_Ternary_Tool%20(Dictionary)/___txt/_ASCII_175,000_word_Mix_A-Z_Multi_Lined.txt through that app that generated that flow diagram.

Comment: @sln, the tool hangs up, but have just tired a little portion and here you go. [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/00gbbQDuHryKaGWX)

Comment: Here is a small one [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/xa32ZR9TnVI7L54w). Only the Z - words, about 791 words. I put in the A -words regex with about 10,000 words, and it took like 3 minutes to make a flow chart, but unfortunately it didn't let me share it ( I guess it won't save it ). It's strange. Using [RegexFormat](http://regexformat.com) it takes 1 second to generate the ternary tree regex, and 2 seconds to format it. They are doing something there that takes a very long time. On these trie's, there is at most 8 pathways.